# Plugin for static code analysis of Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I want to run a static code analysis over my Rails app. Is there a tool available that can help me do this?

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [metric-fu](http://metric-fu.rubyforge.org/) - it bundles various Rails analysis tools and outputs the results to your browser.

I did have some difficulty getting Saikuro (a cyclomatic complexity analyser) to work last time I tried it, but it was a while ago and I can't remember exactly what the problem was now...

Comment: There a couple more options listed here too: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics.html